# Return nth object in a mongo document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a document:

```
{
    _id : 123412341234

    regions : {
        america : [north, south, central]
        europe : [east, west]
        asia : [north, south, east, west, central]
    }

}
```

I want to return the 2nd object (europe) in the regions object of the document by specifying its index.

Example:

```
db.area.find({}, {regions.2 : 1})
```

Return:

```
[east, west]
```

**How do I return the 2nd object (europe) of my regions object?**

Comment: You can't get that value using indexing. Do you want the value where `key==='europe'`?

Comment: Yes. I want the value key==='europe' without specifying that it is regions.europe. I want the 2nd object from regions whatever that might be.

Comment: You can't use indexing because JavaScript doesn't order object property you may want to read this thread.[Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) To do want you want you will need to change your data structure and change `regions` to an array of sub-documents.